# Rewrite rule for redirect url

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to apply rewrite rule for achieve this.

```
current url : http://localhost/mysite/?userlogin

rewrite url : http://localhost/mysite/userlogin
```

I want to do like when any user open http://localhost/mysite/userlogin this url, at that time user must get view of http://localhost/mysite/?userlogin this url.

[Note] : current url is working right now..But I m getting Object Not found on rewrite url.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of web-server are you using and what do your current rewrite rules look like?

Comment: I am using apache2[opensuse] and I tried to find rewrite rule on google which can satisfy this condition, but i was failed. I am new to rewrite rule.

Comment: Could you please add the Rewrite-Part of your htaccess file to your question?

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^?$ /$
@mapek

Comment: Are you using Nginx or Apache?

Comment: @GhanshyamKatriya Please edit your question and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

### If you are using an Apache server

You can do this creating a .htaccess in your web application root directory with this content:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```

If you have more than one site on your root folder, like this:
| root
|_ web1
|_ web2
|_ web3

you need to add a .htaccess file only to the folder that you want to enable rewrite rules, example:
| root
|_ web1
|__ .htaccess
|_ web2
|_ web3

> Note: To use the above solution, you need to enable .htaccess module
>   in Apache2.
>   In your **apache2>sites-available>default** or
>   **apache2>sites-available>your_config**, set [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html) to 'All':

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

**Note: (Edit the code above according to your existing code.)**

### If you are using a Nginx server

You need to add these lines to your nginx server config!

```
if (!-f $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
    set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "21"){
    rewrite /(.*) /index.php?p=$1;
}
```

### If you are using a Windows IIS Server

You need to add a web.config with these rules (I suggest to use the URLRewrite 2.0 in IIS Control panel to add these l

```
<rule name="rule 1Z">
    <match url="(.*)"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?p={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I am using apache2. but this rules doesn't work for me.

Comment: Are you using htaccess?

Comment: yes, and I wan't to achieve this via htaccess only. because If I will change any config file it may affect my other web-portals @Mirko

Comment: But, your websites are in the same folder? Check my updated answer please.