# Redirect and Rewrite Rule for Apache

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to install a CalDAV client on my apache webserver, and I am having trouble using a combination of redirects and rewrite rules to get a desired url.

The document root for my webserver is `/var/www`, and the calendar files are stored in `/var/www/agendav/web/public`. If I go in through my browser at `<website>/agendav/web/public/index.php`, I have no trouble getting to the interface and using it, so that is not a problem. However, my desired URL for the calendar is `<website>/calendar/`, instead of having to go down through the agendav folder tree. I have been trying to perform this with a redirect rule, and a rewrite rule, but to very little success. I have found a few other answers here that have gotten me close, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384618/rewrite-rule-for-redirecting-transparently-to-subfolder) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35646879/rewrite-rule-for-redirect-url), with a working redirect, but I am still having issues with the rewrite rule. Here is the current solution I have:

```
# Rules for the Calendar
Redirect "/calendar" "/agendav/web/public"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/agendav"
RewriteRule "^/agendav/web/public/(.*?)$" "/calendar/$1"
```

My current solution seems a little circular. First, I redirect the user to the agendav folder, then then try to hide the redirect behind a rewrite rule, when it seems that I could just get away with a single rewrite rule. Unfortunately the group I am working for is not big enough to have their own dedicated server manager, and I ended up with the job despite knowing very little about it. Any help to get this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apologies for the indirect response, but if `index.php` is a valid default index file, have you considered just symlinking `/calendar` to `/agendav/web/public`? or does that introduce too much extraneous trouble?

Comment: I had actually not considered symlinking up until this point. Symlinking seems to work as far as I can tell. Are there any foreseeable future issues involved with symlinking?

Comment: It does make the same page available in two places, if that bothers you... but you don't have to expose them both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the redirect, you can do it with just a rewrite rule, the problem was that you have the condition and the rule reversed, you were using the real path for the conditions instead of the "virtual" path:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/calendar" [NC]
RewriteRule "^calendar/(.*)" "/agendav/web/public/$1"
```

With this rules all requests for `http://yourwebsite/calendar/*` are internally served with `http://yourwebsite/agendav/web/public/*`.